# masonry re ordering acting wierd

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I am using masonry for the first time http://masonry.desandro.com/

I have got it all setup and it mostly seems to work but when dragging in its seems to make weird choices on where it places the boxes.

What i mean by this is i might have a medium size object followed by a small object followed by a medium the another small

when i scale in instead of placing the medium on the top line, the two small next to each other on the next line and the other medium one on the bottom it keeps the order which kind of makes the whole thing pointless.

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/danwhitmarsh/zgjBy/

on that fiddle make the bar between the result and javascript bigger and smaller and this will become apparent

here is some example code

html

```
<main id="main" class="js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 320, "itemSelector": ".module","isFitWidth": true }'>
    <!-- INTRO MODULE -->
    <div class="module med-width med-height">

    </div>
    <!--EXAMPLE OF SMALL SMALL MODULE-->
    <div class="module sml-width sml-height">

    </div>

    <!--EXAMPLE OF MEDIUM SMALL MODULE -->
    <div class="module med-width sml-height">

    </div>

    <!--EXAMPLE OF SMALL SMALL MODULE-->
    <div class="module sml-width sml-height">

    </div>

</main>
```

and some css

```
    * {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    font-family: Arial;
}



#main{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.sml-width {
    width: 320px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.med-width {
    width: 640px;
    background-color:#000;
}
.sml-height {
    height: 320px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.med-height {
    height: 640px;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

can anyone help - am i missing a setting?

Answer (score 0):

After speaking to the author he advised me of another product he has

http://packery.metafizzy.co/

This seems to work well. It actually fits blocks into spaces that are missing which masonry didnt do.

Thanks

Dan

Comment: well the issues above where blocks wouldnt fit into the spaces has been fixed and therefore is a resolution the original question.